# Pull and merge a branch with different name to a different repository

Tags: git, github

We have 2 repos like shown in the picture below. One repo is in Bitbucket and the other one in GitHub. For the sake of simplicity, let's say that the URL of repo in Bitbucket is `team-bears-url` and the URL of repo in GitHub is `team-titans-url`

We want to regularly merge the updated from the `share/team-titans` branch on `team-bears-url` into `development/main` of `team-titans-url`. How to accomplish this?

In my local, to my `team-titans` I have added a `team-bears` as a remote using `git remote add bears team-bears-url`. However, I do not know how to merge the contents of `share/team-titans` branch on `team-bears-url` into `development/main` of `team-titans-url`.

I tried `git pull bears share/team-titans:development/main` and it did not work (I have currently checked out `development/main` branch of `team-titans-url`.

Also, as indicated in the picture, parallel development will happen on both `development/main` branch of `team-titans-url` and `share/team-titans` branch on `team-bears-url` and we will have do the pull regularly.

[image]